# JSoup parser not picking up table element

Tags: java, html, css-selectors, jsoup

[JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) here. I have the following HTML:

```
<html><head>
<title>My Soup Materials</title>
<!--mstheme--><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../_themes/ice/ice1011.css"><meta name="Microsoft Theme" content="ice 1011, default">
</head>
<body><center><table width="92%"><tbody>
<tr>
<td><h2>My Soup Materials</h2>

<table width="100%%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left"><b>Origin:</b> Belgium</td>
<td align="left"><b>Count:</b> 2 foos</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="left"><b>Supplier:</b> </td>
<td align="left"><b>Must Burninate:</b> Yes</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="left"><b>Type:</b> Fizzbuzz</td>
<td align="left"><b>Add Afterwards:</b> No</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<b><u>Notes</b></u><br>Drink more ovaltine</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</center></body>
</html>
```

When I run this code:

```
String htmlString = "<html><head><title>My Soup Materials</title><!--mstheme--><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"../../_themes/ice/ice1011.css\"><meta name=\"Microsoft Theme\" content=\"ice 1011, default\"></head><body><center><table width=\"92%\"><tbody><tr><td><h2>My Soup Materials</h2><table width=\"100%%\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\"><tbody><tr><td align=\"left\"><b>Origin:</b> Belgium</td><td align=\"left\"><b>Count:</b> 2 foos</td></tr><tr><td align=\"left\"><b>Supplier:</b> </td><td align=\"left\"><b>Must Burninate:</b> Yes</td></tr><tr><td align=\"left\"><b>Type:</b> Fizzbuzz</td><td align=\"left\"><b>Add Afterwards:</b> No</td></tr></tbody></table><br><b><u>Notes</b></u><br>Drink more ovaltine</td></tr></tbody></table></center></body></html>";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
Elements allTables = document.select("table");
Element table = allTables.get(0);
```

The `allTables` element has a size of 0 and is empty (has no children, no properties, etc.). And so when I go to get the first table I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. **Why?** I would have expected it to have lots of children, starting with "`<h2>My Soup Materials</h2>`", etc.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your config? I ran your exact code (the 4 Java lines) and checked the size in Java 17 with the newest JSoup (1.14.3) and `allTables.size()` returned `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely comes down to something about your configuration or something different in your Java code than what's in your question. I ran the exact 4 lines of Java code from the question and checked `allTables.size()` which returned `2`.

Used Java 17 and the current newest version of JSoup (1.14.3)

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String htmlString = "<html><head><title>My Soup Materials</title><!--mstheme--><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"../../_themes/ice/ice1011.css\"><meta name=\"Microsoft Theme\" content=\"ice 1011, default\"></head><body><center><table width=\"92%\"><tbody><tr><td><h2>My Soup Materials</h2><table width=\"100%%\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\"><tbody><tr><td align=\"left\"><b>Origin:</b> Belgium</td><td align=\"left\"><b>Count:</b> 2 foos</td></tr><tr><td align=\"left\"><b>Supplier:</b> </td><td align=\"left\"><b>Must Burninate:</b> Yes</td></tr><tr><td align=\"left\"><b>Type:</b> Fizzbuzz</td><td align=\"left\"><b>Add Afterwards:</b> No</td></tr></tbody></table><br><b><u>Notes</b></u><br>Drink more ovaltine</td></tr></tbody></table></center></body></html>";
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
        Elements allTables = document.select("table");
        Element table = allTables.get(0);

        System.out.println(allTables.size()); // prints 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### First

your html has two tables

#### Second

html table has sections : header, body, rows,cols, etc. You need to create a more detailed algorithm to get the children

```
Element table = doc.select("table").get(0); //select the first table.
Elements rows = table.select("tr");

//first row is the col names or header, so skip it.
for (int i = 1; i < rows.size(); i++) { 
    Element row = rows.get(i);//get entire row
    Elements cols = row.select("td");//get cols of this row
    //get specific row
    System.out.printl(cols.get(5).text());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JRichardsz (+1) however the problem is that `doc.select("table")` itself is empty (size = 0) and so `doc.select("table").get(0)` throws `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`.

Comment: Please see my edits for a fully-reproducible code example.